# Javascript link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I have this script in my linkbar on the bottom of my page

```
<a href="links.html">
    <span id="cockroachlinks"
        onmouseover="this.innerHTML='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WHAT IS WRONG WITH YOU?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'" 
        onmouseout="this.innerHTML='more dead cockroach related links'">
            more dead cockroach related links
    </span>
</a>
```

And when i click on the link i get a 404 error. I'm positive i uploaded the page and the link is functional. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 404 error means it can't find the file. Double-check that you've uploaded the file with the correct name and extension.

Comment: "more dead cockroach related links" WTF!!!!!!  please check the href. test if the filename and relative paths are correctly set. Is "./links.html" what you want to point to?

Comment: It certainly doesn't have anything to do with the `onmouseover`/ `onmouseout` functions.  Try visiting `http://<whatever>links.html` and see if it shows up.  Check for case sensitivity, the file being in a different folder, and file-access rights.

Comment: In your desktop browser, you can usually right-click on the link and select "Copy Link" or something similar. Then go to your browser's address bar and paste that URL and press Enter. If the browser can't load it, the file probably isn't where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

try to access directly to the file, just to check how your webserver responds do this link.

your link is valid, probably it is a server configuration or a permission or something like that!